# generate json with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have postgreSQL 8.4+PostGIS 1.5.

I want to generate GeoJson. I do:

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc)
 FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features
 FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type
, ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.the_geom)::json As geometry
, row_to_json(lp) As properties
   FROM parcels_temp As lg 
     INNER JOIN (SELECT num, cadastr FROM parcels_temp) As lp 
   ON lg.num = lp.num  ) As f )  As fc;
```

But get an error:

```
 ERROR:  type "json" does not exist
 LINE 4:     , ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.the_geom)::json As geometry
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is this? `ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.the_geom)::json`

Comment: The `json` datatype and the `row_to_json` function was introduced in 9.2 You will need to upgrade.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no `json` data type in PostgreSQL 8.4. The type was introduced in 9.2, though a backport to 9.1 was created; see [this bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/adunstan/json_91).

Use `text`. `json` is just a validating wrapper around the `text` type anyway, the interesting bit is the functions like `row_to_json` - which are *also* unavailable for 8.4.

If you can't use `text` - say, because you're using 3rd party code that expects `json`, or because you need the json functions - then it's time to upgrade PostgreSQL. 8.4 is getting pretty elderly anyway, as is PostGIS 1.5.

Comment: Thanks. It what i want to hear.